# Value of $A_k$ in Fourier series

Tags: continuous-signals, fourier-series

Fourier series in continuous time domain while representing $a_k$ in rectangular form   $$ a_k = B_k + jC_k$$
But when using the value of $a_k$ in the main equation: $$ x(t) = a_0 + 2\sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ 1} [B_k\cos k\omega_0t - jC_k\sin k\omega_0t]$$

I want to ask from where $-$(minus) sign comes as there was no minus sign 
main Equation
$$ x(t) = a_0 + 2\sum^{+\infty}_{k\ =\ 1} 2\mathrm{Re}\left[ e^j(k \omega_0t +\theta_k)\right]$$

Comment: The two equations for $x(t)$ cannot be equal.  The first contains an imaginary component. The second is purely real-valued.  That, and it would be nice to know the relationship between $a_k$ and $\theta_k$.

Comment: That depends on how you exactly define $\theta_k$. Something like this should work $\theta_k = atan(\frac{-C_k}{B_k})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid that all the formulas in your question are inaccurate. From what I understand, you're interested in the representation of *real-valued* signals $x(t)$:

$$x(t)=a_0+2\Re\left\{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}a_ke^{jk\omega_0t}\right\}=
a_0+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Re\left\{a_ke^{jk\omega_0t}\right\}\tag{1}$$

With $a_k=B_k+jC_k$ and $e^{jk\omega_0t}=\cos(k\omega_0t)+j\sin(k\omega_0t)$ you get

$$\Re\left\{a_ke^{jk\omega_0t}\right\}=B_k\cos(k\omega_0t)-C_k\sin(k\omega_0t)\tag{2}$$

which you can substitute into Eq. $(1)$ to get the equation in your question (but without the $j$!). The minus sign in $(2)$ appears simply because $j\cdot j=-1$.

Comment: Yup in understand now, I have posted a [question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/26253/proof-for-determining-fourier-coefficients). please answer me if you have time